# Use scrollview and adjustPan together android

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my manifest I have written

```
 <activity android:name=".email" 
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">         
 </activity>
```

And in my layout I have written

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_backdrop_wave" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText>
        </EditText>

        <EditText>
        </EditText>

        <EditText>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, When I clicked on any edit text it will not re sizes the imageview but It will also disable scroll view.

Now what I have to do to come out, I want such layout in which height of image view will not change and it will stick to align parent bottom while any soft keyboard is open, and scroll view is enable while soft key board is open.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried using

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

This will not resize the imageview, instead it will auto adjust the screen when the keyboard popup

Comment: Yes i tried this, but image view set above the soft keyboard, I don't want to set it above keyboard, I want it alignParentBottom in any situation, is it possible?

Comment: what you want is, to disable the auto resizing and make the layout scrollable

Comment: I want to set image view alignParentBottom if soft keyboard is open, also my layout is scrollable while keyboard is open. I have set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" so my image view is set to bottom if soft keyboard is open but layout is not scrollable.

Comment: Yes I want to disable the auto resizing and make the layout scrollable

Comment: I also had similar problem before..I think the adjustpan and scrollview donot work simultaneously. But if the number of views exceed the screen height, then it will scroll. If i get the solution then i will post the answer.

Comment: i know this question so long time ago, but i wanna know that if the author of this question now get the workaround or not?Now i also get the same problem, i worked on android 2.2 and encountering problem of scrollview and adjustpan of softkeyboard. I cannot scroll my layout to bottom when softkeyboard shown in adjustpan mode. If you already solved this problem, please do me a favor: post your workaround on this thread. I'm very appreciated.

Comment: Same here. Using adjustResize will let me scroll my ScrollView to the bottom, but resizes buttons on the top. using adjustPan retains the height of my buttons at the top but does not let me scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Make sure your Image is inside the single child inside ScrollView aligned to bottom, like this.

```
<ScrollView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          ....

          ....

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_illustration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/some_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_illustration" />

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Add the following properties to **ScrollView**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

Add this to under your activity tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```